# UIPageViewController completion block not called

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks

When i call

```
- (void)setViewControllers:(NSArray *)viewControllers 
                 direction:(UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection)direction 
                  animated:(BOOL)animated 
                completion:(void (^)(BOOL finished))completion;
```

in `UIPageViewController` `delegate`

```
- (void)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController 
        didFinishAnimating:(BOOL)finished 
   previousViewControllers:(NSArray *)previousViewControllers 
       transitionCompleted:(BOOL)completed;
```

I see that completion block not be called. But when i call this method outside of `delegate` method, the completion block is called.
Do i config wrong? could you give me hint!

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post your code, including the completion block?

Comment: Have you set up your delegate properly?

Comment: yes, datasource and delegate already set to self

Comment: This code is call inside and outside of delegate method:
ContentViewController *leftPage = [[ContentViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ContentViewController" bundle:nil];
ContentViewController *rightPage = [[ContentViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ContentViewController" bundle:nil];            
[self.pageViewController setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:leftPage, rightPage, nil]
   direction: UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:YES completion:^(BOOL finished){NSLog(@"completion block");}];

Comment: The problem seems related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24266420/uipageviewcontroller-didfinishanimating-not-called-if-swiped-quickly

 
I can reproduce the problem by: 1. scroll to last page. 2. scroll to previous page a little bit then scroll very fast to end(for triggering the last page bouncing effect)