# UIPageViewController didFinishAnimating not called if swiped quickly

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uipageviewcontroller

I have a UIPageViewController that works as expected. I can scroll left and right and the delegate method `didFinishAnimating` is called when I scroll each direction. However, if I scroll too quickly I end up on a page where `didFinishAnimating` is not called, though it is called for all previous pages. Does anyone know why this might be happening?

I would think that `didFinishAnimating` would be called on every page transition regardless (e.g., even if the turn was aborted).

Comment: I've been investigating this issue for a while and it appears likely it's a bug in the UIPageViewController implementation. I'm debating get rid of UIPageViewController and using a custom UIScrollView implementation to get around this bug.

Comment: It's good to know that someone else was able to reproduce this behavior.

Comment: hi did you get any workaround for this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This bug is still here in 2017.. I tried many alternative ways.. now I gave up the hope that this will be fixed by Apple and I think the best way is to use protocol to bound `UIPageViewController` with content `ViewController`, so we can notify `UIPageViewController` in `viewDidAppear()`

Comment: i had the same issue, i was initialising and assigning `dataSource` and the `delegate` in a same block of code and i noticed that `delegate` methods were not called. Then i assigned `dataSource` while initialising and `delegate` after a background process it was calling `delegate` methods. its a strange bug i guess they(Apple) broke it in 2017.

Answer (score 2):

I've got the same issue. I tried to use the `UIScrollView delegate` instead of `UIPageViewController` to solve the issue. *This is a tricky method, not recommend to use.*

1.get the `UIScrollView` in `UIPageViewController` to set delegate:

```
for (UIView *view in self.view.subviews) {
    if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIScrollView class]]) {
        UIScrollView *scroll = (UIScrollView *) view;
        scroll.delegate = self;
    }
}
```

2.override `scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView`

```
- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:PageSwitchingBegan
                                                    object:nil];
}
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:PageSwitchingEnded
                                                    object:nil];
}
```

You may also try override `- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView` instead of `scrollViewDidEndDragging` to achieve better result.

Comment: This implementation did not cater the situation that people tap on the pageControl dots to switch pages. So you may still need to implement `UIPageViewControllerDelegate` on `willTransitionToViewControllers` and `didFinishAnimating`