# UIPageViewController—— didFinishAnimating

Tags: ios, uipageviewcontroller

PageVC contains A, B and C sub-controllers. Slide to C, and then slide slowly and continuously to A .so that the A page is fully attached to the sides of the screen and then let go. At this point the pageVC proxy method didFinishAnimating method does not run.

Comment: Have you assigned the delegate of the PageViewController to your ViewController?

Comment: I had assigned the delegate. Normal sliding is not a problem. Only slow sliding is a problem.

Comment: You can see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24266420/uipageviewcontroller-didfinishanimating-not-called-if-swiped-quickly

Answer (score 0):

The page view controller.

finished
YES if the animation finished; otherwise, NO.

previousViewControllers
The view controllers prior to the transition.

completed
YES if the user completed the page-turn gesture; otherwise, NO.

Comment: I know this method. I don't know why this method isn't called when I'm sliding slowly